# How to fetch more than 100 records from azure cosmos db using query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I want to fetch more than 100 records from azure-cosmos DB using select query.

I am writing a stored procedure and using a select query to fetch the record.

`SELECT * FROM activities a`

I am getting only 100 records though there are more than 500 records.
I am able to get all records usings the setting configuration provided by Azure.

[image]

I want to perform the same operation using query or stored procedure. How can I do that ??

Please suggest changes that need to accomplish.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to return all records through stored procedure. Correct? Please update your question and include the stored procedure code you have written.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I am writing a stored procedure and using a select query to fetch the record.
>
> SELECT * FROM activities a
>
> I am getting only 100 records though there are more than 500 records.

The default value of FeedOptions [pageSize](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Collection.html#.FeedOptions) property for `queryDocuments` is 100, which might be the cause of the issue. Please try to set the value to **-1**. The following stored procedure works fine on my side, please refer to it.

```
function getall(){
 var context = getContext();
  var response = context.getResponse();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

  var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM c';

  collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, {pageSize:-1 },
    function(err, documents) {
      response.setBody(response.getBody() + JSON.stringify(documents));
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: there is a JSON in cosmos db. I want to pagination in Store procedure, how to do please?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone hits this page, the answers above are obsolete.
`@azure/cosmos` now has some options like below for those who are interested:

```
const usersQuery = {
        query: "SELECT * FROM c where c.userId = 'someid'" +
            " order by c.userId asc,  c.timestamp asc"
    };
const { resources: users } = await container.items
                .query(usersQuery, { maxDegreeOfParallelism: 5,maxItemCount: 10000 }).fetchNext()
```

For reference, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/feedoptions?view=azure-node-latest#maxItemCount).